# Why my two variables cannot add same object? Javascript

Tags: javascript

It is not allow that two variables add same object.
This is a segment.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                    var categoryId= categories[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var categoryName = categories[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var eleOpt = document.createElement("option");
                    var txtOpt = document.createTextNode(categoryName);


                    var catelogryAddOption = new Option(categoryName, categoryId);
                    sel.options.add(catelogryAddOption);

                    sel2.options.add(catelogryAddOption); //Here is an exception.


                }
```

However, it can work when I declare other Object, which is catelogryAddOption2.

```
enter code herefor (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                    var categoryId= categories[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var categoryName = categories[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    var eleOpt = document.createElement("option");
                    var txtOpt = document.createTextNode(categoryName);


                    var catelogryAddOption = new Option(categoryName, categoryId);
                    sel.options.add(catelogryAddOption);

                    var catelogryAddOption2 = new Option(categoryName, categoryId);   //This is catelogryAddOption2
                    sel2.options.add(catelogryAddOption2); // It can work


                }
```

Although the problem is solved, I don't understand the reason.

Does anyone explain it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [`new Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) is a Constructor for creating an HTMLOptionElement. The Option constructor is from the very early days of DOM scripting and has non–standard syntax, but has ubiquitous support in browsers.

`new Option()` returns a `HTMLOptionElement` which is a node by nature.

As per the specifications, *a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position.*

[**Node.cloneNode()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) can be used to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new parent.

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
var select3 = document.getElementById('select3');

var catelogryAddOption = new Option('categoryName', 'categoryId');
select1.options.add(catelogryAddOption.cloneNode(true));
select2.options.add(catelogryAddOption.cloneNode(true));
select3.options.add(catelogryAddOption.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="select3">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/tvvoy61u/1/)

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as - **One element in DOM cannot have two parents**.

If you try to add an already added element to DOM as a child to another element, then it is removed from the earlier element as a child.

Comment: Option gets added to the second(or last) select in _chrome_ so __Once an element is added to the DOM it cannot be added again anywhere else__ does seem ambiguous. Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/tvvoy61u/

Comment: @RayonDabre it gets added in the second select but is then removed from first one https://jsfiddle.net/5k3vhwqn/2/. I agree that line is ambigous, changing the same.